# In which SQL dialect was RANK() first introduced?

Tags: sql, rank, analytic-functions

In which SQL standard was RANK() first introduced?

List of SQL standards:

- SQL-86
- SQL-89
- SQL-92
- SQL:1999
- SQL:2003
- SQL:2008

SQL Rank function: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_(SQL)#RANK.28.29_window_function

References would be most appreciated.

Comment: Why are people voting to close this question as "not a question"?

Comment: not sure why this has a -1... Seems like a good question and probably applicable to devs.

Comment: I would like to know so i can can write my software and state a minimal SQL dialect required, implemented by the persistent store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The analytic features are defined as part of the ANSI SQL 1999 standard

Reference:

- [SS64.com](http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-analytic.html)